# How can i do hover effect on a css sprite image?

Tags: css, sprite

I am using a sprite image. And each icon on sprite has same but different color for hover effect. Well when i mouseover on the icon, hover effect is working. But i would like to get that hover (change image) on div mouseover instead of the span. (since span width specified as icon size, i couldn't find a solution on that)

If you please check below css and html, you'll understand what i need. I want the "search_forums" (span) icon to change on "each_option" div mouseover.

Thanks in advance

**CSS**

```
.each_option{
height:30px;
border-bottom:1px solid #ffe869;
font-size:14px;
padding-top:9px;
color:#707070;}

.forumdisplay_sprite{
background-image:url(../img/forumdisplay_sprite.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display:block;
text-indent:-99999px;
overflow:hidden;}

.search_forums{height:24px;width:24px;background-position:-24px -48px;}

.search_forums:hover{height:24px;width:24px;background-position:-24px -72px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="each_option">
<span class="forumdisplay_sprite search_forums"></span>
<a href="#">Search Forums</a>
</div>
```

**SPRITE ICONS**
[Sprite icons image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeEo3.png)

---

Sorry for not being clear enough. My original/previous style was like on below given page. Then after reading an article about better css and optimizing, i decided to use sprite images. But i have this problem...

Here is what i would like to do : http://jsfiddle.net/stckhlm/EXZKa/

Is it possible to get the hover (change wrapper div's background color and inner div's background image same time) effect like on above example ? If not, then i'll have to stop using the sprite images or hover effect...

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're after right?

http://jsfiddle.net/j4nf4/1/

Unsure why the image you supplied does not render so found another sprite.

Why do you want a span above the anchor? To me that didn't make sense.

If you want a on div hover effect the CSS should be in your case:

```
.each-option:hover {
Your styling here
```

}

Ensure that if you are setting a hover state for divs, spans, paragraphs etc that you change the cursor to pointer: `cursor: pointer;` so that users know that the area / region is clickable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
.each_option:hover .search_forums{//enter your hover changes here.}
```

Not 100% sure if I've understood what you're after - but the code above should do the trick if you're looking to change the search_forums styling when each_option is hovered.